# Drupal Commerce Cc avenue payment not showing Proceed to payment button during payment process

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I have installed [Commerce cc avenue](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_ccavenue) for making payment. All works fine but when redirecting to payment page it displays help text i.e (Please wait while you are redirected to the payment server. If nothing happens within 10 seconds, please click on the button below.). But there is no button in that page which can be seen in the screenshot given as link [Screenshot](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/506420/1ae13632a867f6178b0334ef636fec23)

Comment: does your payment details in form submitting with proper cc avenue credentials and redirect url?

Comment: Yes. Only thing is button is missing